# Proving that $1 \over x_n$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $x_n > 0$ with all $n$. Also $x_n$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ when $n$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$.

Prove by the definition that:

$1 \over x_n$  $\rightarrow$ $\infty$, when $n$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$

I found this to be kind of tricky since it's not "formatted" like the usual ones. How would one approach something like this?

Comment: Since you're asked to prove by definition, the first thing to consider is: what is the definition? (if you know it write it down and try to see if even intuitively the definition makes sense) To be explicit, there are two definitions here: the first is of taking the limit $n \to \infty$, and the second is what it means for the sequence $1/x_n$ itself to approach $\infty$ (as opposed to a finite value); do you know them both?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ah it seems that im not sure what's the second definition. The definition for the limit to diverge looks something like this? $\forall M$ $\exists N$, such that, whenever $n > N$ then $x_n > M$ .

Comment: That's almost right; you instead should have written $1/x_n > M$ in this particular case. I suggest you write out the two definitions:  $x_n \to 0$ and $1/x_n \to \infty$ explicitly and then see how assuming the first implies the second. (the "actual" proof is one-line if you just take a reciprocal in the correct place and phrase the argument properly)

Comment: Hmm, isn't $x_n$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ just the regular definition? $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists N$ such that, for every $n > N$, we have $|x_n - 0| < \epsilon$. I might be blind, but somehow i don't see the implication here...

Answer (score 1):

Let me write both definitions:

- $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$ and means that for every $\varepsilon> 0$, there exists an $N_1 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb{N_1}$, if $n \geq N_1$ then $0 < x_n < \varepsilon$. (actually it should be $|x_n - 0|< \varepsilon$ but I used the assumption that each $x_n > 0$ to simplify this).
- Next, by definition, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x_n} = \infty$ and means that for every $M > 0$, there exists an $N_2 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, if $n \geq N_2$ then $ \dfrac{1}{x_n} > M$.

(I purposely called one of them $N_1$ and the other $N_2$, just to emphasise that there is no reason for them a priori to be the same $N$.)

Now, we shall assume the first statement is true and prove the second. To do this, let $M > 0$ be any arbitrary positive number. We now need to find an integer $N_2 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that blablabla. Now, we shall make use of our assumption. Choose $\varepsilon = \dfrac{1}{M}$; this is clearly a positive number, therefore by our assumption, there exists $N_1 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$,
\begin{align}
\text{if $n \geq N_1$ then $0 < x_n < \varepsilon := \dfrac{1}{M}$} \tag{$*$}
\end{align}

Now, recall our objective: we wanted to find an $N_2$ which works. I claim that we can choose $N_2 = N_1$. What I mean is that I claim  that the statement: "if $n \geq N_2 = N_1$ then $\dfrac{1}{x_n} > M$" is true. This is pretty obvious because:
\begin{align}
n \geq N_2 = N_1 & \implies 0 < x_n < \dfrac{1}{M} \tag{by $*$} \\
&\implies \dfrac{1}{x_n} > M
\end{align}

This completes the proof, because I have word for word checked the definition in the second bulleted point: given an arbitrary $M> 0$, I have shown the existence of an $N_2$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, if $n \geq N_2$ then $\dfrac{1}{x_n} > M$.

---

I hope you realise the logic of the argument. I'm supposed to prove that "for all $M > 0 \dots$" So I started by saying "let $M> 0$ be arbitrary" to make it clear that the argument which follows will work everytime. Then, I used my assumption $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$ and $x_n > 0$ to find some $N_1$. The next part of the proof, I'm supposed to show that "...there exists $N_2 \in \Bbb{N}$..." so I showed exactly what $N_2$ should be, namely in this particular case, I decided to choose $N_2$ to be the same $N_1$ which I found before (I could have chosen $N_2 = N_1 + 1000$, and my argument would still be correct).  Then, finally I showed the implication $n \geq N_2 \implies \dfrac{1}{x_n} > M$, simply by using my given assumption $(*)$ and the rules for manipulating inequalities, thereby completing the proof.

By the way I hope you also notice where exactly in the proof I used the assumption that for all $n$, $x_n > 0$ (this is a very crucial assumption, so be sure that you know where exactly it is being used).

Comment: Ah! This starts to make sense right now. Im only wondering the choice for $\epsilon$. Since for the assumption we can chose anything that’s positive and $1 \over M$ is a positive number it’s a valid choice, but how do we get there? Is it just a logical choice or is there something else to it?

Comment: It seems you are convinced that the proof is right, and indeed $1/M$ is a valid positive choice for $\epsilon$ and it turns out to make the proof work. How did I come up with this $\epsilon$? Well a few years back I struggled alot with this same problem... so its partly an experience thing. But in hindsight, it shouldn't seem too absurd. You want to prove that for large enough $n$, we have $1/x_n > M$. But this implies $0< x_n < \dfrac{1}{M}$. Hence, I decided to take this as $\epsilon$. Note that this is logically completely backwards; but this is often what happens

Comment: Often in such proofs, you have to work "backwards" to figure out what a posiible candidate $\epsilon$ would look like, and after that you have to reverse the argument, so that it flows logically in the "forward" direction. For example, if $x_n \to 0$ and each $x_n > 0$ then it is also true that $\dfrac{1}{x_n^2} \to \infty$. So, in this case, by "working backwards" I would say: I want $\dfrac{1}{x_n^2} > M$. This implies $0< x_n< \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{M}}$. So, in my proof above, I would have chosen $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{M}}$, and then I would rewrite this whole proof in the "forward" manner.